# How to use variable as an alias

Tags: postgresql

I want to use a variable as an alias of schema name.
My goal is to change the values of the variables in case of archiving other clients, so that i will not touch the entire sql code. I have no idea on how to implement it. Is there a way to do this. Thanks in advance

```
BEGIN;

    -- Set clientid
    -- \set thisClient 42951;
    \set thisClient 43527;

    \set archive_schema data_archive_230_test;

    -- create new schema
    create schema :archive_schema;

    select * into :archive_schema.sometable1 from public.sometable1 where account_id = :thisClient;

    select * into :archive_schema.sometable2 from public.sometable2 where id = :thisClient;

    ...more tables here to be archive

COMMIT;
```

Im getting an error when i try to execute the sql above

ERROR:  syntax error at or near "."
LINE 1: .sometable1

Comment: `\set` is a psql command, you can't use it in plpgsql.

Comment: Besides, it seems that you actually want to do `INSERT INTO … SELECT …`.

Comment: I'm running this file on terminal using \i file.sql

Comment: I was able to create the schema, but the "select * into" query isn't working using the schema variable

Comment: This seems vaguely similar to something I had an issue with once; try putting double quotes around the variable, e.g. `into ":archive_schema".sometable1`. Assuming that syntax is even valid - I expect it to look like `CREATE TABLE schema.table AS SELECT * FROM other_table`

Comment: I tried to put quotes but it gives me ERROR:  schema ":archive_schema" does not exist

Comment: Ok, in that case and unless you find a better way around it, I'd suggest that this code should be moved to a plpgsql function, which takes a schema name and client id as parameters. It then uses dynamic sql to execute all the commands. The psql part can pass whatever values to that function. That's what we do for similar stuff.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alternative way is setting default schema

```
BEGIN;

    -- Set clientid
    -- \set thisClient 42951;
    \set thisClient 43527;

    \set archive_schema data_archive_230_test;

    -- create new schema
    create schema :archive_schema;
    -- setting default schema
    SET search_path TO :archive_schema;

    select * into sometable1 from public.sometable1 where account_id = :thisClient;

    select * into sometable2 from public.sometable2 where id = :thisClient;

    ...more tables here to be archive

COMMIT;
```